# Batch searching with Google

Tags: batch-file, search-engine

I am trying to geocode a large number of addresses on a weekly basis. I already have the geocoding software, but the problem is that many of the input addresses are poorly formatted or misspelled, thus resulting in a high rate of unmatched addresses.

Considering Google's proficiency in correcting misspellings, I thought it would be useful to use Google's search engine for preprocessing. Is there a way to do this? Does Google have an API that will take a couple thousand poorly formatted addresses and spit out the corresponding correct ones? I have already tried Google's Geocoding API for address cleaning, but it was about as picky as my geocoding software. Google Maps on the other hand, will see an address like "2341 wmnroe s 54, Springfield, IL 62705" and recognize it as "2341 W Monroe St Springfield, IL 62704". Does Google Maps, or Google search for that matter, have batch searching capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google has an API for search:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview .

I would give Google Custom Search a try, and see how it responds to your poor addresses.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem like this API is the appropriate tool for addresses. It appears to work for just about anything else, but even typing in a correct address would not be read by the custom search.